# wordpress rest api v2 get terms table

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am using wordpress 5.7 and it's rest api v2. I want to get the rows of the `terms` table.

I tried all the api endpoint, but can't find the api to query the rows of terms table.

how can I get the rows of terms table, just as the following sql statement:

```
select * from {table_prefix}_terms;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `terms` table Wordpress stores all the terms like `category` and `tag`, plus your custom taxonomies. You cannot get all terms in one blow. You can, however, use the endpoints for `category` and `tag` to get all the terms.

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags
```